# java.awt.Choice.select(Choice.java:430)

Tags: java, exception, image-processing

I work on image segmentation, this my code for  Image choice

```
m_ImageChoice = new Choice();
for ( int i = 0; i < m_Images.size(); i++ )
  {
  m_ImageChoice.add( ( String ) m_Descriptions.get( i ) );
  }
m_ImageChoice.select( 0 );
m_ImageChoice.setBounds( 20, 270, 230, 30 );
m_ImageChoice.addItemListener( this );
add( m_ImageChoice );
```

but when I run the applet it throw Exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal Choice item position: 0
    at java.awt.Choice.select(Choice.java:430)

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html#select(int)):

> Throws:
>
> `IllegalArgumentException` - if the specified position is greater than the number of items or less than zero

Your argument isn't less than zero, so it must be "greater than the number of items". If that's the case, `m_Images.size()` was zero.

(Actually, there's a typo in the Javadoc here, it should say "greater than **or equal to**", since [that's the check in the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Choice.java/#429))